# Downloading SoilGrids data globally using R

Tags: r, download, soilgrids

I'm trying to download the ISRIC SoilGrids data via R (Version 3.6.2 on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5) as described in the tutorial here:
https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/soilgrids-access

Following this guide I can download the data for the small example bounding box. However, I'm interested in the global data so my modified R script looks like this:

```
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)

bb=c(-20037500,-6729000,20037500,8600750) #bounding box parameters (in Homolosine) for whole globe, as suggested on the website 
igh='+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' #proj string for Homolosine projection


gdal_translate(
  '/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt',
  "./crop_roi_igh_r.vrt",
  of="VRT",
  tr=c(25000,25000),
  projwin=bb,
  projwin_srs =igh,
  verbose=TRUE
)


gdalwarp(
  "./crop_roi_igh_r.vrt",
  "./crop_roi_ll_r.vrt",
  s_src=igh, 
  t_srs="EPSG:4326", 
  of="VRT"
)

gdal_translate(
  "./crop_roi_ll_r.vrt",  
  "./crop_roi_ll_r.tif", 
  co=c("TILED=YES","COMPRESS=DEFLATE","PREDICTOR=2","BIGTIFF=YES")
)
```

Running

```
gdal_translate(
  '/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt',
  "./crop_roi_igh_r.vrt",
  of="VRT",
  tr=c(25000,25000),
  projwin=bb,
  projwin_srs =igh,
  verbose=TRUE
)
```

aborts with the following error message:

> Checking gdal_installation...
> GDAL version 2.4.2
> GDAL command being used: "/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_3/bin/gdal_translate" -tr 2500 2500 -projwin -20037500 -6729000 20037500 8600750 -of "GTiff" -projwin_srs "+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" "/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt" "./crop_roi_igh_r.tif"
> ERROR 1: -projwin_srs ignored since coordinate transformation failed.
> Input file size is 159246, 58034

What I tried so far:

1. incrementally increasing the bounding box from `bb=c(-337500.000,1242500.000,152500.000,527500.000)` 
   up to `bb=c(-19861874.000, 1242500.000, 19861874.000, -1500000.000)`

This spans a belt from -179.xx to 179.xx Longitude but I can't increase Latitude parameters even to 20°N/S before encountering the error.

2. Going for a different parameter (mean clay content, which I'm actually more interested in) via

```
gdal_translate(
  '/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay/clay_0-5cm_mean.vrt',
  "./crop_clay_igh_r.vrt",
  of="VRT",
  tr=c(25000,25000),
  projwin=bb,
  projwin_srs =igh,
  verbose=TRUE
)
```

This gives the error

> ERROR 1: Error: Computed -srcwin 71784 36135 16030 -6132 has negative width and/or height.
> Input file size is 159246, 58034

Comment: Why do you have the cell size set to 25000 and not 250?

Comment: Mainly to increase download speed (if it worked). Setting the resolution to 250 gives the same error.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.StackExchange, please take [the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not done so. Your question is a bit convoluted, if you need the whole grids, why not simply download them from the WebDAV service? Afterwards you can easily re-project them to your favourite CRS.

Comment: Another thing: internally those grids are already in GeoTiff format, you gain nothing in converting them with `gdal_translate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the tutorial](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/soilgrids-access) has been updated to take into account this error.

The call to `gdal_translate` was failing when providing the global bounding box. The call is working without those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I was also unable to follow their tutorial, so I made some custom scripts that are basically web scrapping from their online map. Check it out:

https://github.com/zecojls/downloadSoilGridsV2

Answer (score 0):

Check out also these tutorials:

- https://rpubs.com/ials2un/soilgrids_webdav
- https://github.com/ISRICWorldSoil/GSIF_tutorials/blob/master/SoilGrids250m/tutorial_SoilGrids250m.R